# How to use Variable for grep inside Ksh script

Tags: linux, grep, scripting, variable, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
Temp=Kerala
cs1=`grep "$Temp" State_list.txt | awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $cs1 #("Not seeing output KL":
```

If I change the code as follows, it works:

```
cs1=`grep "Kerala" State_list.txt | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

... but I would like to pass it as variable.

The file State_List.txt is as follows:

```
Karnataka KAR
TamilNadu TN
Kerala    KL
```

Comment: Bash or ksh the shebang says `#!/bin/ksh`?

Comment: That looks like it should work (with ksh, or bash, or dash). Make sure you don't have any typos there, or weird invisible characters. If the data file has windows style CRLF line endings, it shouldn't matter, but if the script file does, you'll assign `Kerala\r` to the variable, and you won't be able to find that in the file. But then you might also get an error when running the script, since the hashbang would be wrong.

Comment: if change as following .(Harding to "kerala" it works. But Question is How to pass the variable. ...   cs1=`grep "Kerala" State_list.txt | awk '{print $NF}'`.. Thanks

Comment: @natrajeee20, yes. How do you run the script? Did you check the line endings?

Comment: @ilkkachu .. file name is test.sh   (Following is command:  ksh test.sh)

Comment: @natrajeee20, well, now that you've ignored my other point twice, I could mention it a third time, or just leave you to it.

Comment: @ilkkachu. I am seeing "CRLF" ending in each line inside the State_List.txt

Comment: @natrajeee20: Then that is probably the issue. Change the line endings to just LF and see if things work?

Comment: @natrajeee20 The issue is with possible CRLF line endings in _the script_. If there is an extra `\r` at the end of each line, then `$Temp` will not be `Kerala` but `Kerala\r`, which is why it doesn't match in the indata file. Changing the indata file form DOS text to Unix text would obviously _also_ be a good thing to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda .. U got it.. it worked !!!! Thanks a Lot ^_^

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved in the comment section.

Summary:

The files, both the script and possibly also the data file, were DOS text files.  On Unix, that means that they had a superfluous `\r` (carriage return) at the end of each line.

For the script, this meant that the variable assignment

```
Temp=Kerala
```

assigned the value `Kerala\r` to the variable `Temp`.  Since the data file did not contain this value, it was never found.

Running the script with the value inserted in place of the variable worked since it, at that place in the data, was not affected by the DOS text issue.

The utility `dos2unix` should be installed and run on both files to make sure that they are Unix text files.  See also [other questions on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=dos2unix) relating to this utility.

---

The script could also have been written like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

Temp='Kerala'
cs1=$( awk -v pattern="$Temp" '$1 ~ pattern { print $NF }' State_list.txt )
printf '%s\n' "$cs1"
```

This gets rid of the `grep` and uses `awk` in its place to scan for any line in the in-data file's first column that contains `pattern` (a variable assigned to `$Temp` on the command line).  With `==` in place of `~` an exact string matching is performed rather than a regular expression match.

The script is an `sh` script since it (and the original) does not use any special `ksh` features.